# Evaluating $\int\frac{x^4}{x^2+a^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

Please how to integrate the following function?
$$
\frac{x^4}{x^2+a^2}
$$

Comment: You have been on this site long enough to know that **context** is essential when asking a question. Please tell us what you have tried and where you get stuck.

Comment: I am sorry. I joined a long time back but started using it 3 days ago only. I will keep that in mind from later on. Thanls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**. One may start with
$$
\frac{x^4}{x^2+a^2}=\frac{(x^4-a^4)+a^4}{x^2+a^2}=x^2-a^2+\frac{a^4}{x^2+a^2}
$$ then one may use
$$
\left(\frac{1}{a}\arctan \frac{x}{a} \right)'=\frac1{x^2+a^2}.
$$